# JSTS : How to union of more then two polygons in openlayer2 using JSTS library

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am doing a project In which I have to take union of many polygons if their edges are intersecting.Polygons maybe more then 100 but they have to make a union shape. Till now I just found that in jSTS we can by using

> a=b.union(c);

But It is not working for me as its just for 2 polygons.

My code is

```js
 

   var strGeom = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(geom);
   var parseGeo = reader.read(strGeom.toString());
   union = parseGeo.union(parseGeo);
   var parser = new jsts.io.OpenLayersParser();
   union = parser.write(union);
   console.log(union);
   var strGeom = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(union);
```

[image: Just like that]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the code for JSTS union

https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/blob/master/src/org/locationtech/jts/operation/union/UnaryUnionOp.js (line 16/17)

you can pass a geometry collection instead of a single geometry.

Otherwise, you could perform a union for each polygon.

Something like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < polygonsLength; i++) {
    geom = geom.union(polygons[i]);
}
```

Comment: I want to take input in single object array and then its union if the points are intersecting .Is it possible with it ?